# How to privately track issues?

Tags: issue-tracking, bug, collaboration

I'm working on a certain group repository. This repo has an issue tracker, but - it's not intended for all issues, and certainly  ot for our day-to-day development work. The point is - I need to track issues with my code (and perhaps the code of others ) - myself.

How would you suggest I do this "private issue tracking"? Should I just use a text file or a spreadsheet? Or is there some kind of personal issue tracker you would recommend? Or maybe something else entirely?

I should mention the code is not FOSS, so I can't just fork the code and track issues on my own repo.

Note:

- I'm not using a physical implement like a notebook or whiteboard for several reasons: 1. Expecting to eventually convert/combine these into filings on the public tracker, maybe. 2. If push comes to shove, I use a plain text editor, not a physical notebook, typically 3. Sharing with people who are not physically next to me.
- The simple default is to just write down the issues I see in plain text format. But if there are more than, say, 15-20 of these, that gets cumbersome; and I want to be able to have links between the issues, to tag them, and the features I would usually have on an issue tracker. I just feel that setting up one just for myself is a bit of an overkill.

Comment: If the issue tracker of the repo isn't suitable, why not chose any off the shelf issue tracking software and set it up just for your group, or alternativly use sticky-notes on a wall or whiteboard as a kanban board?

Comment: @bdsl: I said privately, not at the group level.

Comment: ah ok - I was thinking you were part of a small group which shared the repository with a wider group, and you wanted to track issues just for the small group.

Comment: What has led you to *not* use any of the obvious solutions (a notebook, a whiteboard, Trello, sticky notes, a Notes app, index cards, a spreadsheet, literally just a piece of paper, any kind of text/document file, ...)?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: See edit. Also, I've never used Trello. Now that you mention it, I do vaguely remember it has something to do with issue tracking. I should look it up.

Comment: Half of those things *aren't* physical.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I did mention my fallback is leafpad/notepad/gedit.

Comment: So why aren't you just doing that? What's the problem you're trying to solve? And what if anything does what is fundamentally just *writing a list* have to do with software engineering?

Comment: Did you actually *try* using a simple text file? If yes, why doesn't it suit your needs?

Comment: @DocBrown: I am using a simple text file. I'll expand my question to explain why that's not satisfactory.

Answer (score 4):

**Use the same tools as you would for a team**

Without suggesting specific tools, which is fairly out of scope - the main thing to focus on, is you are never an "individual" engineer on any project.

You are at very least, a team of 1 person, who has 1 future collaborator (that may also be yourself).

Moreover, you will find you are actually handling the responsibilities of multiple roles; the developer, your own manager and the product owner. If these were 3 different people, you wouldn't think twice about using a "proper" solution - so similarly, to enable you to do these roles properly you need to do the same.

As such, treat your task management the same way as you would for a team. Which also tends to mean using existing bug or task tracking software - being clear in your descriptions, and then assigning the workload to yourself when appropriate (depending on your development methodology).

Answer (score 1):

*While tool recommendations are off topic for this site, I will attempt to answer this without recommending a tool, and strictly stay within practices that a programmer could use in their own code base.*

---

This is where `//TODO` and `//FIXME` comments tend to be used. Many IDEs will automatically parse these comments and create a list, which you can view right in the IDE. For instance Visual Studio has a window called Task List:

[image: Screenshot of task list in Visual Studio 2019]

Other IDEs will have something similar, but basically that's how we track issues privately. It's either a TODO or FIXME.

These sorts of comments don't need to be one-liners, like `//FIXME: returns true when it should return false`. Sometimes the problem can cut across many files or application layers. Just pick a file and make your comment long enough so you can remember fully after coming back:

```
/*
   TODO: add logging around all calls to database

   - check repositories
   - controllers
   - investigate AOP loggers
*/
```

These comments can (and do) sneak in to your main branches in version control. An alternative to comments is to write failing unit tests in order to capture the intended behavior and replicate the problem. This works great for code bases designed for unit testing; not so great for code bases not designed for unit testing. The nice thing about failing tests is how obvious the right behavior is, and the fact the test fails is a big fat red flag that this is still work in progress. Accidentally checking in a failing test that gets run in a continuous integration build will give you pretty quick feedback that you may still have a `//FIXME` or two laying around.

Comment: So, this works for issues that are local to a single line, or at most a single file. But yeah, this would be part of it so +1.

Comment: @einpoklum: I updated my answer. You made a good point.